# Why does typescript require names in function types?

Tags: typescript

Why do we need to name the parameter types in the type annotation of functions?

```
let f: (a:number, b:number) => number;
```

Why is `a` and `b` required here?

Comment: It's a design decision on the TS designers part. They are there for semantic documentation.

Comment: Becsuse a good variable naming is a key to an efficient and readable code. Without argument names you will have to provide an annotation for every parameter. Parameters like a and b make no sense for another developer, while haystack and needle are self-descriptive

Comment: Which one do you find more clear `(string, string, number) => Person` or `(firstName: string, lastName: string, age: number) => Person`?

Comment: Although I agree with those who say it is clearer to require names, it is worth pointing out that there would be a syntactic ambiguity if names were optional.

Comment: @AluanHaddad why is that?

Comment: @Thomas because given the type `(x) => y` there would be no way to know if `x` was the name of the parameter or the type of the parameter

Comment: but it could just be only the type in there right @AluanHaddad

Comment: @Thomas but the parameter type is an optional part of a function type so how could the language know if `(x) => y` meant `(x: any) => y` or `(anonymousParameter: x) => y`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a design decision to make the code more readable. Also parameters in "normal" functions also need a name. Let's take the example of you using a libary which includes arrow functions, what do you think is easier to use of the following two examples?

```
const getResult: (string, number?, number?) => queryObject;
```

or

```
const getResult: (id: string, startIndex?: number, endIndex?: number) => queryObject;
```

I hope this makes it clear to you